# Excel - Getting cell of duplicate cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making an inventory system in Excel and cannot figure out how to get all cell values that are duplicates. So far I have this formula to find how many duplicates. I need to find the cell row of the duplicates so I can get the values and preform other calculations.

The cells in B column contain text
J column contains only integers

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$99999,B11) > 1, "more than one duplicate", "no duplicate")
```

What I would like the formula to do:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$99999,B11) > 1, ("J" + DuplicateCellRow1) + ("J" + DuplicateCellRow2), "no duplicate")
```

Edit:
Here is some
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARBnU.png)
The Yellow is duplicate products with different UPC codes. This happens because we order from different suppliers and none of them use similar codes. I basically want to add up all the similars from "QTY" into the "Combined QTY" column.

e_conomics suggestion worked, however the second duplicate is also printing out a number. Is there a way to prevent that or to filter it out? This is a master file so I will be creating nicer looking reports in a different sheet

Comment: Use a SUMIFS to sum the values in column J

Comment: `IF(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$99999,B11) > 1, SUMIFS($J3:$J$99999,$B3:$B$99999,B11), "no duplicate")`

Comment: Can you show some sample data? You may need `TEXTJOIN()` function with `FILTER()` and `COUNTIF()`.

Comment: Thank you e_conomics, that worked.... with some side effects. Please see the edit.

I appreciate your help

Comment: @RobinYoHood should combined QTY of duplicate #2 = combined QTY of all duplicates or qty of duplicate #1 + duplicate #2?

Comment: Duplicate QTY + Duplicate QTY = Combined QTY

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a slight adjustment to the formula.The cell referencing was incorrect.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$99999,B3) > 1, SUMIFS($J$3:$J$99999,$B$3:$B$99999,B3), "no duplicate")
```

Paste this into K3 and drag down.

Comment: Works, but still has that side effect of the second duplicate calculating a different number as seen in my edit screenshot

Comment: I changed the referencing. The sumifs should be on column J (qty). Anything with a duplicate will have the same combined quantity.

Comment: There was a $ missing from my comment above. Copy and paste the latest answer.